# Proofs Practice Calculus 2

Tags: calculus

I'm in calc 2 and I sometimes try to make my own proof problems so that I can prepare for harder math later on. Does my answer make sense for this problem. Where can I improve in terms of how I have written this proof?

> Rigorously prove that $\sin(x)$ on the closed interval $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $ has 1 minimum and 1 maximum each at an endpoint. Imagine you know what all functions look like but you do not know what $\sin(x)$ looks like.

I was thinking that I could use the derivative $\cos(x)$. An extremum on a function $f(x)$ for a closed interval can only occur at one of three places: where $f'(x)=0$, $f'(x)$ is undefined or at the endpoints. On $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $, $\cos(x)$ has no undefined points and the y-values are never zero. Thus, the extrema on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $, if they exist, can only occur at the endpoints of the interval. Because $\cos(x)$ is the derivative, since it's continuous on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $, $\sin(x)$ must be continuous on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $. According to the extreme value theorem, $\sin(x)$ must have at least one maximum and at least one minimum on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}]$ because of this continuity. Because I only have 2 endpoints, the only combination of maxima and minima that has a total number of extrema being 2 is 1 minimum and 1 maximum. So, on $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}] $ $\sin(x)$ has a 1 minimum and 1 maximum, each at an endpoint.

Comment: That's basically correct.  You should mention that $\sin x$ is continuous and you should mention you are citing the extreme value theorem and then... you don't really need to say anything else.  A fairly direct corollary of the extreme value theorem is on a closed interval if a continuous function has a continuous derivative on the interval, then the function is mono increasing or decreasing and has max, min on the endpoints.

Comment: @fleablood I don't get how the corollary is correct. If I have $x^2$ from -1 to 1 it's not mono increasing nor mono decreasing.

Comment: But $f'(x) = 2x$ and it equals $0$ in the interval and.... argh.... my fingers forgot to type that part... didn't they? Basically I'm just saying to same result as you did.  that if $f'(0)$ is never $0$ then function is mono inc/dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. I find it strange that you write that “Because $\cos(x)$ is the derivative, since it's continuous on $\left[\frac\pi6,\frac\pi3\right]$, $\sin(x)$ must be continuous on $\left[\frac\pi6,\frac\pi3\right]$.” Since $\sin$ is differentiable, it is continuous. That's all. The exact value of $\sin'(x)$ is not relevant, and much less the fact that $\sin'$ is continuous.

You could have added that, since $\left(\forall x\in\left[\frac\pi6,\frac\pi3\right]\right):\cos(x)>0$, then $\sin$ is strictly increasing on that interval. Therefore, the minimum is attained at $\frac\pi6$ and the maximum at $\frac\pi3$.